# Quantitative adjective declension: "Ich habe der Frau jedes einzelne Foto gezeigt."

Tags: adjective-ending

We're learning about quantitative adjectives like **ander-**, **einig-**, **viel-**, and so on in German.

We were presented with the following sentence that's supposed to be demonstrating weak declension of the adjective(s):

> Ich habe der Frau jedes einzelne Foto gezeigt.

How is this a weak declension? It's weak only for einzelne, but jedes here is strongly declined is it not? Since it's "das Foto", and therefore "jedes ... Foto". Why wouldn't "einzelne" also be "einzelnes"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need at most one strong declension. "Jedes" is strongly declined, so "einzelne" only needs to be weakly declined

Comment: I guess "jeder" is different? We were told that if determiners like "viele, einige, andere, etc" are used in the strong declension, then any adjective that follows is also strong.